# Идти на цыпочках

Tags: этимология

Кур мы созываем призывом "цып-цып". Птенец курицы - цыпленок (кстати, совершенно не понятно, почему у утки - утенок, а у курицы - не куренок). Так вот, почему тогда, когда человек идет тихо, поднявшись для этого на пальцы, называется "идти на цыпочках"? Связано это как-то с цыплятами? Может быть, имеется в виду, что идущий на носках человек уподобляется курице?

Comment: В немецком auf den Zehenspitzen (цейншпитцен) ... согласитесь, подозрительно похожее звучание с цыпочками. Не может ли быть простонародным подражанием

Comment: Даже непохоже. А кто кому звукподражает-то? Народ немецкому языку?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Цыпки, цыпочки, цыпленок, цып-цып и проч.- слова безусловно родственные.
Но это еще вопрос, кто кому уподобляется.

Все слова восходит к звукоподражательному "цып",  - тихий, беззвучный, шаг, "цыпать" - тихо, неуклюже ходить. Известно с XII века, но наличие родственных во всех славянских и, возможно, балтийских позволяет предположить гораздо более древнее возникновение.

Почему именно так передан этот тихий скрип при ходьбе - для меня загадка, возможно дело в тогдашней обуви. Куры очень тихо и медленно ходят, поэтому понятно возникновение "цыплака" (цыпленка), и понятно, что оно тут не первично, а производное от тихого шага. А вот цыпочки - уже может быть интерпретировано по-разному. Или напрямую из "цыпать", либо, наоборот, от "ходить подобно курице" - на пальцах. Первое, все-таки вероятнее. Т.е. "цыпочки" - не потомок "цыпленка", а его двоюродный брат или точнее - двоюродный дядя.

Совсем непонятно (мне), как в этом ряду появились "цыпки" - красноватые язвочки на руках или ногах, с трещинками и пузырчатыми крошечными волдырями.

Answer (score 2):

Цыпленок - это птенец цыпли (в соответствии со словообразованием).  Тогда сын цапли - цапленок? Нет, цапленком его не называют, хотя цапля к призыву цып-цып имеет прямое отношение.

"Цапля ходит по болоту, Ждут в гнезде ее птенцы". Впрочем по болоту цапля, скорее, не ходит, а цапает-чапает, то есть хлопает, шлепает, неуклюже семенит. И еще у цапли длинные тонкие ноги с цепкими пальцами  (правда, добычу цапля не цапает, но резким и очень быстрым броском выпрямляет шею и хватает ее клювом).

Тем не менее у звукоподражательного глагола цапать  два разных значения: **хватать и  медленно ступать.** Такие  слова относят к так называемому "звуковому жесту". Разнообразие их значений - явление вторичное. Цапнуть - это и царапнуть тоже. Да и цыпки на коже - это тоже царапины.

А ходить на цыпочках - это «ходить на кончиках пальцев ног».

Про "цыпочки"

"И. И. Дмитриев  писал: «Выражение на цыпочках вместо на пальцах употребительно было доселе не между авторами, а деревенскими только старухами»  Этот последний протест И. И. Дмитриева — против слова на цыпочках — ярче всего показывает, как расплывчаты были границы «литературного» просторечия, при отсутствии твердых норм". 
http://slovarionline.ru/istoriya_slov/page/tsyipochki.1422

Answer (score 1):

> Цыпленок - это птенец цыпли (в соответствии со словообразованием).

Отнюдь. Это уменьшительное от цыплак )))
Тот кто цпает, цыпляет.